# Haskell Couldn't match expected type involving maybe

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell and I have run into a problem but I don't really understand what is the problem. When I compile the code below, it tells me "Couldnt match expected type 'integer' with actual type 'Maybe Integer'" for line 17:19 and again the same error for 17:27.

```
maybe_divide :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
maybe_divide a b = case valid_div a b of
True  -> Just (a `div` b)
False -> Nothing

valid_div :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Bool
valid_div a b
    | a == Nothing = False
    | b == Nothing = False
    | b == Just 0  = False
    | otherwise = True
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `maybe_divide`, the types of `a` and `b` are `Maybe Integer`....  You can not divide `Maybe Integer`s

```
a `div` b --won't work
```

You will have to "unwrap" the `Maybe` values, extract the `Integer`s before you use them in `div`.  (There are a few ways to do this, including pattern matching).

Comment: If you don't feel like manually unwrapping maybes, `liftA div a b` is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but im not sure what @genisage means by that...
Also, can you elaborate a simple way to extract Maybe Values?

Comment: @WhatDoor You're unwrapping maybe values in your question.

Comment: @WhatDoor- A clean way to unwrap would be to use `case` and pattern matching, or just use pattern matching at the function definition level.  A less clean way would be to use `fromJust` (which can crash if you accidentally give a `Nothing`)....